# Monitor and Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am checking if my queue is full or not like

```
lock (SizeQueueProperty.Locker)
{
    while (_queue.Count >= _maxSize)
    {
        SizeQueueProperty.Waiting = true;
        Monitor.Wait(SizeQueueProperty.Locker);
    }
    _queue.Enqueue(item);
    if (_queue.Count == 1)
    {
        // wake up any blocked dequeue
        SizeQueueProperty.Waiting = false;
        Monitor.PulseAll(SizeQueueProperty.Locker);
    }
}


public static class SizeQueueProperty
{
    public volatile static object Locker = new object();
    public volatile static bool Waiting;
}
```

if is then in another class in another thread checking this code:

```
if (SizeQueueProperty.Waiting)
{
    Log.Info("Waiting for continue on crawling");
    Monitor.Wait(SizeQueueProperty.Locker);
    ....
    More code
}

...
```

is is full i would like to wait that queue get empty and then continue with thread execution. But I always get meesage :

> Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized
>   block of code.

Why?

Comment: I suspect you got into this trouble by trying to add logging.  Consider raising an event in the 1st snippet instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Wait` method from documentation.

> Releases the lock on an object and blocks the current thread until it
>   reacquires the lock.

You should call `Wait` on object only when you hold the `lock`,

```
if (SizeQueueProperty.Waiting)
{
    Log.Info("Waiting for continue on crawling");
    Monitor.Wait(SizeQueueProperty.Locker);
}
```

This code doesn't seems it holds the lock, Does it?

Comment: No it doesno't. So what I need. Simple lock? Like lock (SizeQueueProperty.Locker)

Comment: I add lock (SizeQueueProperty.Locker) but thread now never waits. Always continue execution... Should be volatile?

Comment: Can't guess with this info provided, you may need to tell what you're trying to achieve. As hans said if you need to just log the info you can just add an event and log it

Comment: No there is more code. I want to protect executing the code if other threads in other classes are not finished

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too- "Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code." I was calling Monitor.Enter(Variable) to a **value type**. In my instance it was an integer. I solved it by using an instance of object. RowIndex as my integer i wanted to lock. so i changed my code to:

```
Private SyncObj As New Object

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Threading.Monitor.Enter(SyncObj)
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = RowIndex / Dt.Rows.Count * 100
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = (Dt.Rows.Count - RowIndex).ToString & " left"
        Threading.Monitor.Exit(SyncObj)
End Sub
```

And then in my other thread, I would lock SyncObj before making any changes to RowIndex. Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the need of the original code in .NET 4.5 can be achieved by using 
[BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx)